# aws java driver not looping through keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have the following code:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
    ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName( "myBucket" )
            .withPrefix(path));
   System.out.println("path we need: " + path);
    List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();
    System.out.println(summaries.size());
    do {
        listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : listing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
        }
        listing.setMarker(listing.getNextMarker());
    }
    while(listing.isTruncated());
```

Which seems to partially work.  The lines

```
   System.out.println("path we need: " + path);
   System.out.println(summaries.size());
```

Print out lines that I expect.  However when it loops over the `S3ObjectSummary` it prints nothing out.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to get the next set of truncated objects before printing out your info.  If nothing is truncated, this may be why you're not getting a result.  I suggest changing your loop code to match the following and trying it again.

```
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(creds);
    ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("myBucket").withPrefix(path));
    System.out.println("path we need: " + path);
    System.out.println(listing.getObjectSummaries().size() + " | " + listing.isTruncated());
    while(listing.getObjectSummaries().size() > 0) {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : listing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
        }
        if(!listing.isTruncated()) break;
        listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
        System.out.println(listing.getObjectSummaries().size() + " | " + listing.isTruncated());
    };
```

I've tested this on one of my own S3 buckets and it appears to work as intended for me.